abstract classes in typeorm when defining entities with relations
I have the following two entities for BookTree and BookTreeContent:
import { BookContentEntity } from '@src/modules/book/entities/book-content.entity';
import {
  Column,
  CreateDateColumn,
  DeleteDateColumn,
  Entity,
  OneToMany,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  UpdateDateColumn
} from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class BookEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;

  @DeleteDateColumn()
  deletedAt: Date;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column({ unique: true, default: null })
  slug: string;

  @Column({ default: null })
  description: string;

  @OneToMany(() => BookContentEntity, (content) => content.book, { cascade: ['soft-remove'] })
  content: Array<BookContentEntity>;

  constructor(partial: Partial<BookEntity>) {
    Object.assign(this, partial);
  }
}

import { BookContentType } from '@src/core/enums/book-content-type.enum';
import { BookEntity } from '@src/modules/book/entities/book.entity';
import { FileEntity } from '@src/modules/file/entities/file.entity';
import {
  Column,
  CreateDateColumn,
  DeleteDateColumn,
  Entity,
  ManyToOne,
  OneToMany,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  UpdateDateColumn
} from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class BookContentEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;

  @DeleteDateColumn()
  deletedAt: Date;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column({ unique: true, default: null })
  slug: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => BookContentEntity, (parent) => parent.children, { nullable: true })
  parent?: BookContentEntity;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  parentId?: string;

  @OneToMany(() => BookContentEntity, (child) => child.parent)
  children?: Array<BookContentEntity>;

  @Column({ default: 0 })
  order: number;

  @Column({ type: 'enum', enum: BookContentType })
  type: BookContentType;

  @Column({ default: null })
  content: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => BookEntity, (book) => book.content, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    onUpdate: 'RESTRICT',
    orphanedRowAction: 'delete',
  })
  book: BookEntity;

  @OneToMany(() => FileEntity, (attachment) => attachment.bookContentAttachments)
  attachments!: FileEntity[];

  constructor(partial: Partial<BookContentEntity>) {
    Object.assign(this, partial);
  }
}

I have some other trees with common properties and I want to use abstract classess to write less code. The simple idea is to use the following abstract class:
@Entity()
export abstract class TreeContentEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;

  @DeleteDateColumn()
  deletedAt: Date;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column({ unique: true, default: null })
  slug: string;

  @Column({ default: 0 })
  order: number;

  constructor(partial: Partial<TreeContentEntity>) {
    Object.assign(this, partial);
  }
}

But I want to somehow put there parent and children relations as well. I tried this (chat GPT):
import {
  Column,
  CreateDateColumn,
  DeleteDateColumn,
  UpdateDateColumn,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  ManyToOne,
  OneToMany,
  Entity
} from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export abstract class TreeContentEntity<T> {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;

  @DeleteDateColumn()
  deletedAt: Date;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column({ unique: true, default: null })
  slug: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => this.constructor as () => TreeContentEntity<T>, (parent) => parent.children, { nullable: true })
  parent?: T;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  parentId?: string;

  @OneToMany(() => this.constructor as () => TreeContentEntity<T>, (child) => child.parent)
  children?: Array<T>;

  @Column({ default: 0 })
  order: number;

  constructor(partial: Partial<TreeContentEntity<T>>) {
    Object.assign(this, partial);
  }
}

but it does not work. Any ideas?
